# iCloud for Windows 10: Unable to change location of Shared Photos folder

Tags: icloud, windows

I've recently moved my Pictures folder into a OneDrive folder on Windows. Within the Pictures folder I had my iCloud Photo folders; this required me to update the location of the various iCloud Photo folders in the iCloud settings. This works fine for the Download and Upload folders, but when I try to update the location for the Photo Sharing folder, it always resets to the previous location.

Here's what it looks like before I've set it:
[image]

Note the filepath for iCloud Photo Sharing is `%USER%\Pictures\iCloud Photos\Shared`.

Here's what it looks like after I click the change button and set it to the desired new location:

[image]

Note that the iCloud Photo Sharing path is now `%USER%\OneDrive\Pictures\iCloud Photos\Shared`.

If I then click "Done" to exit to the main options panel, "Apply" to apply the changes, and re-enter the Photos Options panel, I see that the change didn't go through (though it noticeably has for the Download and Upload folders):

[image]

How can I move the folder and make it stick? It doesn't seem to be a conflict with OneDrive, since even if I direct it to a folder that's not archived by OneDrive, it won't keep the change for the Shared Photos location.

Answer (score 2):

After digging through the registry, I found the key that sets this location in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Apple Inc.\Internet Services\iCloud Photos\Settings`. The way to fix this is to change the value of `SharingPath` to the desired location.